# How do I display website logo when I share it on social networks

Tags: html, facebook, share

I need to make social networks for example facebook.com to display website logo when someone put link on it in post, message or share it. I have googled this question and found that website should have this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```

and

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.lucida.construction/wp-content/themes/lucida-theme/images/logo_for_sn.png" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Home - Lucida ConstructionLucida Construction" />
```

but it doesn't give any result. I tried to do this on Facebook and LinkedIn and both of them either not showing an image at all or display some random image and not the logo that I've set in the `<meta property="og:image" />` tag.

Website I try to share are http://www.resolutemarine.com and https://www.lucida.construction

Any help appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you did is correct. I don't know about other social media channels but facebook caches the information of your page. So if have you shared your link before the results are probably cached before you made the change in your code (inserting the og:image part). I don't know when facebook exactly clears it but you can do it manually by using their tool (again). 
I tried it with one site of your linked domain and it works for me.
So if you want to test it use their tool. Otherwise you just need to wait until they grab it automatically.
Here is the link to the tool - just enter the url that you want to be crawled again by the bot: [Facebook sharing debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to share my website sometime and it kept on showing me the website logo, till I had to uninstall all plugging and it still didn't work not knowing it was the All in one SEO plugging that I selected a default image when shared on social media, so if you have AIOS installed, kindly check the settings=> Social Networks and selected the social media you want to change the profile picture if you have it installed

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32902466)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).